# How can I get data from column N in pandas read_excel

Tags: python, pandas, excel

How can I get data from column N in pandas read_excel.
For example, when there is Excel data as below, please tell me how to get it in the format of row 2~, column B~.

```
pandas.read_excel(file_path, skiprows=1, usecols=B:)
```

`[usecols=B:]` ←I don't know this part.

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |
|  | Cell B2 | Cell C2 | Cell D2 |
|  | Cell B3 | Cell C3 | Cell D3 |
|  | Cell B4 | Cell C4 | Cell D4 |

Comment: `usecols="B"`(quotes)

Comment: Thank you for answer, TheMaster.
In the case of [usecols="B"], only the data in column B is obtained. I want to get the data from column B to the last column.

Comment: You can't with the `read_excel` API. Either pre-read the column names and pre-filter to only pass the wanted names to `read_excel`, or read everything and post-filter.

Comment: I found out that with the read_excel API you have to specify the start column and end column. As you said, I think I need to use a different method to check and get the last column, then use read_excel, or use a method to get the desired value in post-processing. Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this df.iloc[1:,1:4]
read the excel and put it in dataframe and after that use iloc to remove unwanted row and column and show the actual data

Comment: Thank you for answer. After converting to DataFrame, I was able to use iloc to get the value from the beginning of the desired row and column. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

usecols="B:E" specifies that you want to extract data from columns B to E. Replace ‘E’ with the last column letter in your Excel sheet.

```
import pandas as pd

# Replace 'file_path' with the path to your Excel file
data = pd.read_excel(file_path, skiprows=1, usecols="B:E")  # Replace 'E' with the last column letter in your Excel sheet

# Print the data from row 2 onwards
print(data)
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. Like the comments above, I've found that the read_excel API doesn't give me the results I want. After reading the data with read_excel, and then converting it to DataFarame, you can get the desired value. thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read from a specific column to Nth column, you will need to know how many columns/fields are available in the excel file that is being read. There are two ways to do it.

First approach:

```
df = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx",sheet_name='Sheet1',usecols=(2,3,...,n))
```

Second:

```
df = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx",sheet_name='Sheet1',usecols='B:XFD')
```

As XFD is the last column in excel sheet, by providing this like the dataframe will have the data until the last column. Say your column ends at Z or AD or BX, the dataframe will have until that column only.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for answer. usecols is where you must specify the columns.
I think (B:XFD)'s idea is a good idea.
It was very helpful. thank you